# How do I start a script at login?

Tags: 10.10, server

How do you run a script when a user logs in? I have created a script script.sh and used chmod +x to make it executable where would I place the script to make it startup when a user logs in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script `~/.profile` is executed at each login, you can put your script here.

But be aware that if you login in two different virtual terminals, the script will be executed twice.

Comment: ~/.profile (which also calls ~/.bashrc) is only executed when logging into a shell (through Terminal or SSH for example). Not when logging into the GUI.