# How to set ccpd daemon to start automatically at startup?

Tags: lubuntu, printing, scripts, canon, startup-applications

After installing a Canon printer in Quantal, in order to print I have to start ccpd at each restart with the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

This should be automated, says the driver manual. But before doing that, I believe that a script for that command must be created. Or is there a way to make the command run at startup without creating a script first? Whether a script must created or not, I guess a different command should be used, one that doesn't open the terminal and doesn't ask for the password each time.

I guess the answer might be like [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown), editing `/etc/rc.local`. That file looks like this:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh -e
> #
> # rc.local
> #
> # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
> # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
> # value on error.
> #
> # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
> # bits.
> #
> # By default this script does nothing.
>
> exit 0
> ```

But what should I do: just paste the command in the line 13 before `exit 0`? And what the command should be exactly?

(A supplementary question that I should ask is maybe this: should that command be put to start with the computer or only at login, or  is that unimportant?)

---

Considering similar questions on Askubuntu, beside the fact that I am not sure what the command is:

- [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/236982/47206) looks promising, but the answer was not set as definitive, and I need more advice. Also, I am in [Lubuntu and do not have](https://askubuntu.com/q/220162/47206) the Ubuntu GUI that adds stuff at startup. The same for [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/79113/47206).
- also [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/34845/47206): but its answer only concerns where to put the script not how to create it, and I guess the comment there drastically amends the answer ("~/.profile (which also calls ~/.bashrc) is only executed when logging into a shell (through Terminal or SSH for example). Not when logging into the GUI")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to assign it a run-level. Something like this should do it:

```
  sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults
```

Here is some more information:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

Answer (score 2):

This should add it to the autostart:

`sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults`

Comment: both answers are identical the other one a few minutes earlier so i put that as definitive.

Comment: I think i was on the page for a few minutes before i answered, so didn't see the other pop up, so fair enough :)

Answer (score 2):

I have looked a long time on the internet how to get it starting automatically. I proceeded as follows:

1. I read canon's manual in next link:
   http://software.canon-europe.com/files/soft28622/readme/README-capt-1.6xE.txt
2. Reading how to login as root in ubuntu 13.04 in next link: 
   http://linuxg.net/enable-login-as-root-on-ubuntu-13-04/

Then I proceeded as follows:

- open terminal:
- enterred `sudo passwd root`
- used same password as normally (2x)
- entered `sudo su`
- entered: `echo 'greeter-show-manual-login=true' >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
- exited terminal
- logged-off
- logged in using the word `root` as login and the chosen password (I had filled in in the terminal)
- Opened Nautilus - clicked on (computer on the left hand side and then) the folder `/etc` - scrolled down and found the file `rc.local`
- opened the file: added the line `/etc/init.d/ccpd start` just before line `exit 0`
- saved the file
- opened terminal (still as root otherwise you will not be able to shut down pc) and entered `sudo passwd -l root` to disable root.
- logged-out as root
- logged in as normal user
- shut down pc
- restarted pc
- opened terminal and used command line `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status` to check status.

I got it to work.

Important previous steps I took, but which I do not really know are neccesary: I added to startup applications

1. `sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults`
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

This is how I proceeded and it worked. There is probably an easier way, but this procedure garanties it will start up automatically.

Greetings

Comment: this answer helped me, [I didn't logged-in as root](http://askubuntu.com/questions/319743/is-there-an-easier-or-more-correct-way-to-open-gedit-as-root/319941#319941) (cuz I failed at it) and didn't need start-up-apps. I think both measures are not needed. I also needed to add an extra line to /etc/rc.local (see my own answer). Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to autostart the ccpd deamon on Ubuntu 13.04 by adding `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` to the startup-applications.

**Update:**

This stopped working for me some time ago. 
When I entered `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status` in a terminal it returned one number in stead of two.

Starting the ccpd deamon was no longer posible without stopping it first, so I had to enter `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd stop` en then `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` in a terminal.

It made no difference whether I added `sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults`, `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` or nothing at all to the startup-applications. I also tried ibrahims method. ccpd status returned just one number.

**The solution:**

I added

`sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd stop`

`sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

to `/etc/rc.local`.

*I added nothing to the startup-applications*