# I can't use the terminal while gedit command is running

Tags: gedit

I recently installed 12.04.
When I try to edit a file with **gedit**, I can't use the terminal until I close the editing file or I have to open a new terminal. But I think I didn't have this problem with 11.04, however I'm not sure.
Is there anyway to avoid this and to use same terminal while editing files.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### Short Answer

In the unresponsive terminal:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
2. Type `bg` and enter.
3. Type `disown` and enter.

### Long Answer

In the unresponsive terminal, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, this will "pause" the process (or "job") and return the console control to you. However, you'll notice that `gedit` becomes unresponsive and you can't use it.

> **Extra**: if you want to, you can execute the command `jobs`, you'll notice that it'll read **Stopped** for the `gedit` command, that's why you can't use it.

To make the job successfully run in the background (i.e. to make `gedit` responsive again), execute the command `bg` (meaning background). You'll now be able to use `gedit`, and at the same time have the prompt to yourself.

> **Extra**: now, if you  execute `jobs`, you'll notice that it'll read **Running**.

You can overcome all of this from the very beginning. When you're launching `gedit` from the terminal, add an `&` to the end of the command, so something like this `gedit /path/to/file &`. This will launch `gedit` in the background from the first place (you might need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a couple of times to get the console control back).

> **Extra**: if you were following these extra notes, you might have noticed that the second time you did `jobs`, you could see that bash added a `&` to the end of the `gedit` command.

Once you get used to this system, you might notice that if you close the terminal, gedit will also terminate, without even a confirmation dialog. To prevent this from happening, run `disown`, which will detach the gedit process from the terminal, removing it from the list returned by `jobs`.

Comment: It's always surprised me that there is no way to immediately background a process that's running in the foreground. You *have* to pause it first, which sometimes isn't viable.

Comment: @detly read the part "You can overcome..." again!

Comment: @guntbert - Doesn't help if the process is already running...

Answer (score 49):

Just type:

**`gedit <filename-to-edit> &`**

*This will immediately return the command prompt to you.*

Comment: This is an important unix idiom, and worth knowing. Any command can be run in the background this way. Tools that are interactive obviously will be confused by this treatment, but for example bubblesort war_and_peace.txt % will allow your sorter to crank away at the masterpiece (for a long, long time) while you get on with your work (say, implementing quicksort or something)

Comment: @JonKiparsky Amusing example - does make the point.

Answer (score 24):

You could use the `nohup` to prevent the GUI to be attached to a terminal:

```
nohup mupdf some.pdf &
```

This will allow you to close the terminal you are launching from, without the program being closed.

You should also notice, that the nohup command will create a file with the `stdout` and `stderr` of the command you run. If you want to prevent that, add `&>/dev/null` before the `&`.

```
nohup mupdf some.pdf &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: "nohup" stands for "no hang up". This dates back to early Unix, when (physical) terminals were regularly attached via telephone lines, and you'd therefore close a terminal by hanging up the phone.

Comment: Additional information: The nohup command will create a file `nohup.out` containing output from the command. This is useful if you want to view error messages. If you don't want the file to be created, add redirection as follows: `nohup mupdf some.pdf &>/dev/null &`

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `disown` command. It is particularly useful when you've already started the process you no longer want attached to the terminal.

The basic procedure if I remember correctly, is something like this:

```
$ > firefox      #Oops
Ctrl + z         #Suspend the process
$ > bg           #Push the process to the background
$ > disown       #Detach most recent process started or stopped
$ > exit         #Terminal gone!
```

Note that disown is `bash` specific.

[This blog post explains both methods pretty well.](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3935306/Detach-Processes-With-Disown-and-Nohup.htm)

[Man page for disown](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/man/man1/disown.html)

Comment: A shortcut: `firefox & disown`

Answer (score 13):

From `man gedit`:

> ```
> -b, --background
>          Run gedit in the background.
> ```

So, if you run `gedit` with `-b` option, it will start in background:

```
gedit -b [FILE-NAME]
```

Moreover, next you can create an alias for `gedit -b` (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414/147044) how to create a permanent alias):

```
alias gedit='gedit -b'
```

From now, in the future you can use `gedit [FILE-NAME]` as normal and it will start in background.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use alias to redefine common commands. You'll find lots of threads about it on stackexchange. It is fine to use an alias with a different name. In a nutshell, aliasing existing commands creates unexpected behavior on your machine if someone else ever uses it (like when trying to help you fix some other problem) and it does the same thing to you when you use another system without those aliases and your commands don't work as you expect. One of the poster children for this is alias rm='rm -i'. It gets you used to deleting things with a second chance that's not always there.

Answer (score 11):

Just type:

```
gedit FILENAME & disown
```

Ending a command with `&` in bash runs that command in the background. However, that process is still attached to the terminal.

<s>Without `disown`, if you close the terminal, gedit will close, without even prompting you to save an edited file. `disown` detaches the background process from the current terminal, so that if you close the terminal, gedit will continue to run as normal.</s> Turns out I was wrong, this is not the case for bash, but it is the case for zsh. You still need to run `detach` after doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> and `bg`, though, even in bash.

<sub>You can find out more about the built-ins `jobs`, `disown` and the `&` metacharacter in the [manpage for the `bash` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash), especially the section labelled "job control".</sub>

Comment: with `disown` I was able to keep the gedit open after terminal closed. I didn't get what you said about " this is not the case for bash, but it is the case for zsh"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you opened gedit via terminal. When you do this, you see the command line output that is normally hidden if started via the GUI. The best way to fix this is to open a new terminal window. The other will become available after gedit closes. You can also use the switch the above user suggested.

Comment: A new terminal window just clutters the desktop, even if it's minimized. Using & with or without disown is much simpler and cleaner.