# Open file browser from terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

What is the command to open the current directory in file browser from terminal? Let's say I am in my home folder on the terminal and I want to open file browser. I tried `nautilus --browser` but there seems to be a command that continue to keep running and I can't continue with further commands in the terminal.

Comment: It doesn't open file browser and exit. The command keeps on running in the terminal.

Comment: whats your OS?? try `xdg-open .`

Comment: You can't continue with further commands because you are running it in the shell *foreground*. Use `nautilus &` or `xdg-open . &` to place the command in the background. See for example [I can't use the terminal while gedit command is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319843/i-cant-use-the-terminal-while-gedit-command-is-running)